# Why am I getting a 403 error “CSRF token missing” with Spring boot+ Angular 7?

Tags: spring-boot, angular7, csrf-token

I'm implementing csrf in Spring Boot+Angular 7 Application, my concern is when I am doing login then I can login into the application without any issue. But After login csrf cookie is not changing so that I am getting 403 (CSRF is expired) error from the server,

But when I do refresh then it will work properly. main reason is that cookie is not fetching properly, I don't know that where issue is coming, like from Client Side or Server Side. Please help

I am sharing my code

**Spring Boot Code**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().csrf() // csrf config starts here
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/", "/login", "/captcha-servlet", "/validateOTP", "supportApp/logout")
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CustomCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}


private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

**CSRF Filter**

```
public class CustomCsrfFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Angular CSRF Code**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) { }
```

```
const _csrf_token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
return this.http.post(this._singleuserUrl, uid, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', _csrf_token), withCredentials: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to import **HttpClientXsrfModule** into app.module.ts

Work for me in Angular 6.

**app.module.ts**

```
    imports: [
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
      headerName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
      }),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpXSRFInterceptor, multi: true },
    ...
  ],
```

Additional, I use interceptor to set token into HEADER

**HttpXSRFInterceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpXSRFInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
    const respHeaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(respHeaderName, token) });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Besides, you could use postman to clarify if the config in server works OK.

Hope it could help.